# How do I stop TopShelf creating multiple log files using log4net?

Tags: windows-services, log4net, topshelf

One of my TopShelf-hosted Windows services is creating duplicate log files that look like this:

```
myapp.20140729.log
myapp.20140729.log.20140729.log
```

A similar problem has been described on StackOverflow before - the solutions in [10639682](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10639682/log4net-rollingfileappender-generates-duplicate-logs) didn't work for me, but [579688](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579688/why-is-the-date-appended-twice-on-filenames-when-using-log4net) suggests it could be caused by initialising the logging system twice.

I'm using the TopShelf Log4Net plugin, but I'm also doing my own log4net logging and need access to the `ILog` instance before the service has actually started, so my code looks like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
    XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    var log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyService));
    var container = new Container();
    RegisterComponents(container, log);
    log.InfoFormat("Starting MyService");
    RunService(container);
}

public static void RunService(Container container) {
    HostFactory.Run(x => {
        x.Service<PortalAdaptor>(s => {
            s.ConstructUsing(name => container.Resolve<MyService>());
            s.WhenStarted(f => f.Start());
            s.WhenStopped(f => f.Stop());
        });
        x.RunAsLocalService();
        x.SetDescription("My Service");
        x.SetDisplayName("My Service");
        x.SetServiceName("MyService");
        x.UseLog4Net();
    });
}
```

I've done a little digging, and it appears that calling `x.UseLog4Net()` in my `RunService` method is actually running `XmlConfigurator.Configure()` **again** - see [Log4NetLogWriterFactory, line 62](https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf/blob/32c92aefc3426085f52c3f756eaf57ecab06b1be/src/Topshelf.Log4Net/Logging/Log4NetLogWriterFactory.cs#L62) in the TopShelf code.

So...

1. Am I correct in thinking that calling `XmlConfigurator.Configure()` twice could be the cause of my duplicate log file issues?
2. If so - how can I either inject an existing config into TopShelf, OR get the TopShelf initialization to run before I start my service so I can start logging before the service starts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `Hostfactory.New` instead of `HostFactory.Run` to get a reference to the host, do your logging, then call the Run() method on the host:

```
var host = HostFactory.New(configureService);
var log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyService));
log.InfoFormat("Starting MyService");
host.Run();
```

An alternative approache would be that once you have done your initial logging, call [`LogManager.ResetConfiguration`](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.LogManager.ResetConfiguration_overload_1.html) to clear the configuration and allow TopShelf to reload it:

> Resets all values contained in the repository instance to their
>   defaults. This removes all appenders from all loggers, sets the level
>   of all non-root loggers to null, sets their additivity flag to true
>   and sets the level of the root logger to Debug. Moreover, message
>   disabling is set to its default "off" value.